# Process Codes in the Middle of a SequentialTransition- JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I am trying to execute a SequentialTransition, but between the animations, I need to execute some commands.

My problem is that it is always executing the last commands passed on the node. Is there any way to fix this?

Where is "is ignored" is the code that I need to be executed in the first animation, then where this "is executed" is the code that I need to be executed in the second animation.

Thanks

```
private void startAnimation(){

    vb_adv.setPrefWidth(197);
    ap_services.toBack();// Is ignored
    vb_adv.toFront();// Is ignored
    ScaleTransition expandAdvertising = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(2000), vb_adv);
    expandAdvertising.setToX(2);
    expandAdvertising.setCycleCount(2);
    expandAdvertising.setAutoReverse(true);

    ap_services.setPrefWidth(124);
    ap_services.toFront();//is executed
    ScaleTransition expandService = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(2000), ap_services);
    expandService.setDelay(Duration.seconds(3));
    expandService.setToX(3.7);
    expandService.setCycleCount(2);
    expandService.setAutoReverse(true);

    SequentialTransition sequence = new SequentialTransition(expandAdvertising, expandService);

    sequence.play();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify? When you say "code that is executed *in* the first animation", do you mean that you want that code to be executed *before* the first animation starts? And then the `ap_services.toFront()` to be executed when the first animation ends, and the second animation is about to start? It would also be really helpful if you could create a [MCVE] and post it in the question.

Comment: As a side note, *please* learn and use proper [Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). It is surprisingly difficult for other programmers to read your code if you don't adhere to these.

Comment: Exactly, follow the image to clarify.

First animation 2 (expandAdvertising) is performed, then image animation 1 (expandService).

However, when animation 1 is executed, it must be in front of the screen, otherwise the animation is performed behind component 2.

The same thing when it is the other way around, I need that whatever is running is in front of the screen.

However at runtime it only executes the last command of the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code as you currently have it, you move `ap_services` to the back of the z-order, and `vb_adv` to the front:

```
ap_services.toBack();
vb_adv.toFront();
```

Then you create and set up you `ScaleTransition`. Note that doing this part takes essentially no time; all you are doing is configuring the animation which will run later.

The next thing you do is to move `ap_services` to the front:

```
ap_services.toFront();
```

Note that this will happen essentially immediately after the previous calls to `toFront()` and `toBack()`, and of course this negates the effect of those calls. So your initial calls are actually executed (not "ignored"), but you immediately do something which undoes their effect.

What you really want is to execute `ap_services.toFront()` *after the `ScaleTransition` finishes*. You can do this by putting that call in an `onFinished()` handler:

```
// ap_services.toFront();
expandAdvertising.setOnFinished(e -> ap_services.toFront());
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed.

Thank you very much for your help and sorry for the code, I will rewrite it.

Thanks again.

Comment: One more question that I'm not finding on StackOverflow: Can I pause the animation before the autoReverse command is executed?

Comment: @KelvynCavalcante Not with a `ScaleTransition`. But you could, e.g. use a `Timeline` and have two keyframes with different timepoints and the same endpoint for the scale.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, would I then have to create a Timeline with a keyframe to expand and one to retract between one animation and another I set the start / end time?

Comment: I think you just need three key frames; one with time 0, key value `vb_adv.scaleXProperty()` and 1, one with time 2 seconds, key value `vb_advscaleXProperty()` and 2, and one with, say, time 2.2 seconds and the same key value. Then set `autoReverse` to true as before, etc.

Comment: Cool, I'll try, I'll send you news. Thanks again.

Comment: It worked friend !!!

However, now the animation is expanding to 2 sides, how can I expand only the left side?